# Get data from promise and use it in hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make hook to get data from Snapshot to display proposals. I use `graphql-request` library to get data. I want to get this data in component for example: `const { data } = useSnapshotProposalsQuery()`. How can i do this? For now i can only get `const  data  = useSnapshotProposalsQuery()` and when i am `console.log(data)` i get `Promise{<opening>}`. My code:

```
import { gql, request } from 'graphql-request';

export const useSnapshotProposals = gql`
  query Proposals {
    proposals(
      first: 20
      skip: 0
      where: { space_in: ["example.eth"] }
      orderBy: "created"
      orderDirection: desc
    ) {
      id
      title
      body
      choices
      start
      end
      snapshot
      state
      author
      space {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const useSnapshotProposalsQuery = () => {
  return request('https://hub.snapshot.org/graphql', useSnapshotProposals).then((data) => data);
};
```

Comment: `useEffect` might help you here but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a custom hook. and that hook returns a state. when sideeffect inside that hook happens, the state is updated and your outer component gets re-rendered. ([react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook))

```
export const useSnapshotProposalsQuery = () => {

  const [myData, setMyData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
   request('https://hub.snapshot.org/graphql', useSnapshotProposals).then((data) => {setMyData(data)});
  }, []); // run only one time

  return myData;
};
```

in outer component:

```
function ABCcomponent () {

 const myData = useSnapshotProposalsQuery(); // it will be null at first, but will be filled with data later.
 
 return (
  /*ui that uses myData */
 )
}
```